# iOS custom Bar Button Item's width is always fixed to 44?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I created two custom UIBarButtonItems from interface builder and assigned them both width of 20.

However, the result is both of UIBarButtonItem have a fixed width of 44. As shown in this screenshot:

[image: excessive white space between UIBarButonItem]

Is there a way to reduce the width of these UIBarButtonItems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can init any UIView class as a UIBarButtonItem 
Here is a UIButton...

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_bar_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button sizeToFit];
[button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

That button will size to fit the image my_bar_button.png... can be any size..

Answer (score 0):

add uibuttonin uibarbuttonitem and adjust its width/height as required

Comment: This was an unfair -1

Comment: this is an alternate solution bt not unfair

Comment: how cud v make one understand this unfairness or complaint abt it

Comment: I've marked it up and posted the code you described as well.. Hopefully that'll be enough :)